# Android: OpenGL reloading textures

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

I am trying to add a loading screen into my app as it takes some time to load off of the textures. This is what I was doing before...

```
 public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {         
         super.onSurfaceCreated(gl, config);
         if(firstTimeCreate) {
             load();            //load settings
             Assets.LoadTextures(this);
             firstTimeCreate = false;} 
          else {
            //When screen is resumed....
            Assets.reloadTextures();}
```

This way after the app was resumed the else statement would take effect and reload everything...I tried to adapt it to this

```
else {
            //When screen is resumed....
            Thread aThread = new Thread()
            {
                public void run(){
                    boolean once = true;
                    while(once)
                    {
                        Assets.reloadTexutres();
                        once = false;
                    }
                }
            };
            aThread.start();
        }
```

However it just seems now that OpenGL cant bind the textures as the screen is white. What is going wrong by adding a thread to this method? Do I need to wait for all the textures to load before I let OpenGL start to try and render, if so how can I load one and then present a loading screen until the rest are done?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a way to load textures asyncly?

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL ES context is assigned to a thread. So, if you want to create context in one thread and use it in another thread, you should call `eglMakeCurrent(...)` function.

Comment: ah, do you mean that because these textures are being created within the thread, OpenGL doesnt have knowedlge of it? If that is right what is the work around? Sorry I dont have an EGL surface

Comment: You can't call rendering functions from different threads. So, if you created EGL context in one thread that means the context can be use only in this thread. If you need to work with the context from another thread, you have to unbind context from one thread and bind to another. It can be done with `EGL10.eglMakeCurrent` function.